# How do I get multiple output dataframes into one large dataframe from web scraping multiple pages?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

1. I am very new to python and have no idea where to begin to get this problem resolved. I have been able to get multiple pages of tables formated to a pandas dataframe, but I would like them to be in one large data frame rather than multiple small ones

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

hdr = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

for x in range(1,61,20):
    url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&r='
    r = requests.get(url+str(x), headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class':'table-light'})
    headers = []
    for i in table.find_all('td')[:11]:
        title = i.text
        headers.append(title)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns= headers)
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row_data
    df.to_csv('all.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve your goal:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm ## if using Jupyter: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm 

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in tqdm(range(1, 61, 20)):
    r = s.get(f'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&r={x}')
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table[id="screener-views-table"] table[class="table-light"]')), header=0)[0]
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(big_df)
big_df.to_csv('some_fin_data.csv')
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
3/3 [00:01<00:00, 2.04it/s]
No. Ticker  Company Sector  Industry    Country Market Cap  P/E Price   Change  Volume
0   1   A   Agilent Technologies, Inc.  Healthcare  Diagnostics & Research  USA 45.44B  35.44   155.35  -0.96%  1443781
1   2   AA  Alcoa Corporation   Basic Materials Aluminum    USA 8.59B   -   48.51   -1.72%  3213397
2   3   AAAU    Goldman Sachs Physical Gold ETF Financial   Exchange Traded Fund    USA -   -   17.38   0.64%   2781472
3   4   AAC Ares Acquisition Corporation    Financial   Shell Companies USA 1.25B   46.51   10.00   -0.05%  2537
4   5   AACG    ATA Creativity Global   Consumer Defensive  Education & Training Services   China   50.93M  -   1.72    2.38%   2302
5   6   AACI    Armada Acquisition Corp. I  Financial   Shell Companies USA 206.69M -   9.98    -0.05%  91802
6   7   AACIW   Armada Acquisition Corp. I  Financial   Shell Companies USA -   -   0.03    0.00%   0
7   8   AADI    Aadi Bioscience, Inc.   Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 315.29M -   13.17   -1.86%  45328
8   9   AADR    AdvisorShares Dorsey Wright ADR ETF Financial   Exchange Traded Fund    USA -   -   49.17   0.53%   2232
9   10  AAIC    Arlington Asset Investment Corp.    Real Estate REIT - Mortgage USA 88.94M  46.97   3.10    2.99%   122458
10  11  AAL American Airlines Group Inc.    Industrials Airlines    USA 9.30B   -   14.42   3.15%   23630403
11  12  AAME    Atlantic American Corporation   Financial   Insurance - Life    USA 61.09M  23.65   2.98    4.56%   383
12  13  AAN The Aaron's Company, Inc.   Industrials Rental & Leasing Services   USA 346.97M 23.51   11.85   1.37%   507153
13  14  AAOI    Applied Optoelectronics, Inc.   Technology  Semiconductors  USA 63.96M  -   2.18    -4.39%  159890
14  15  AAON    AAON, Inc.  Industrials Building Products & Equipment   USA 4.22B   62.62   78.65   -1.13%  141623
15  16  AAP Advance Auto Parts, Inc.    Consumer Cyclical   Specialty Retail    USA 9.10B   19.37   150.55  0.67%   1841506
16  17  AAPD    Direxion Daily AAPL Bear 1X Shares  Financial   Exchange Traded Fund    USA -   -   26.28   -0.46%  59190
17  18  AAPL    Apple Inc.  Technology  Consumer Electronics    USA 2394.19B    24.76   151.07  0.59%   58192555
18  19  AAPU    Direxion Daily AAPL Bull 1.5X Shares    Financial   Exchange Traded Fund    USA -   -   21.22   0.66%   13827
19  20  AAQC    Accelerate Acquisition Corp.    Financial   Shell Companies USA 400.80M -   10.02   -0.05%  68967
20  21  AAT American Assets Trust, Inc. Real Estate REIT - Diversified  USA 1.64B   39.89   27.92   -1.38%  233450
21  22  AATC    Autoscope Technologies Corporation  Technology  Scientific & Technical Instruments  USA 25.59M  53.47   5.03    0.53%   16509
22  23  AAU Almaden Minerals Ltd.   Basic Materials Gold    Canada  33.64M  -   0.24    3.56%   141687
23  24  AAWW    Atlas Air Worldwide Holdings, Inc.  Industrials Airports & Air Services USA 2.84B   8.15    100.92  0.13%   168608
24  25  AAXJ    iShares MSCI All Country Asia ex Japan ETF  Financial   Exchange Traded Fund    USA -   -   63.44   0.87%   431419
25  26  AB  AllianceBernstein Holding L.P.  Financial   Asset Management    USA 4.15B   12.08   40.93   -0.58%  336015
26  27  ABB ABB Ltd Industrials Specialty Industrial Machinery  Switzerland 61.86B  15.27   31.44   0.93%   1030745
27  28  ABBV    AbbVie Inc. Healthcare  Drug Manufacturers - General    USA 276.75B 21.23   159.39  -0.25%  3218694
28  29  ABC AmerisourceBergen Corporation   Healthcare  Medical Distribution    USA 32.87B  20.59   165.53  0.50%   916086
29  30  ABCB    Ameris Bancorp  Financial   Banks - Regional    USA 3.60B   10.57   52.67   -0.53%  175672
30  31  ABCL    AbCellera Biologics Inc.    Healthcare  Biotechnology   Canada  3.98B   17.52   14.00   0.14%   1040716
31  32  ABCM    Abcam plc   Healthcare  Biotechnology   United Kingdom  3.74B   459.43  16.08   2.10%   177164
32  33  ABEO    Abeona Therapeutics Inc.    Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 66.51M  -   3.94    -4.14%  195905
33  34  ABEQ    Absolute Select Value ETF   Financial   Exchange Traded Fund    USA -   -   28.27   0.42%   11336
34  35  ABEV    Ambev S.A.  Consumer Defensive  Beverages - Brewers Brazil  45.51B  19.21   2.92    1.74%   19875513
35  36  ABG Asbury Automotive Group, Inc.   Consumer Cyclical   Auto & Truck Dealerships    USA 4.05B   5.18    181.90  1.16%   74043
36  37  ABGI    ABG Acquisition Corp. I Financial   Shell Companies USA 193.49M -   10.01   0.00%   130565
37  38  ABIO    ARCA biopharma, Inc.    Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 29.90M  -   2.10    0.96%   8556
38  39  ABM ABM Industries Incorporated Industrials Specialty Business Services USA 2.97B   14.24   45.30   -0.90%  155214
39  40  ABMD    Abiomed, Inc.   Healthcare  Medical Devices USA 17.02B  64.93   377.78  -0.06%  801762
40  41  ABNB    Airbnb, Inc.    Consumer Cyclical   Travel Services USA 62.14B  40.31   96.63   1.42%   4328409
41  42  ABOS    Acumen Pharmaceuticals, Inc.    Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 278.70M -   6.36    0.79%   103296
42  43  ABR Arbor Realty Trust, Inc.    Real Estate REIT - Mortgage USA 2.42B   8.77    14.44   -1.37%  1212811
43  44  ABSI    Absci Corporation   Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 221.28M -   2.20    0.00%   136066
44  45  ABST    Absolute Software Corporation   Technology  Software - Application  Canada  701.66M -   10.20   4.83%   119574
45  46  ABT Abbott Laboratories Healthcare  Medical Devices USA 182.52B 23.81   106.02  1.10%   4617364
46  47  ABUS    Arbutus Biopharma Corporation   Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 416.56M -   2.70    1.50%   635974
47  48  ABVC    ABVC BioPharma, Inc.    Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 24.70M  -   0.73    -3.31%  6456
48  49  AC  Associated Capital Group, Inc.  Financial   Capital Markets USA 881.43M -   40.60   -0.85%  591
49  50  ACA Arcosa, Inc.    Industrials Infrastructure Operations   USA 2.83B   28.62   58.87   -1.31%  160255
50  51  ACAD    ACADIA Pharmaceuticals Inc. Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 2.40B   -   15.00   -0.27%  788928
51  52  ACAQ    Athena Consumer Acquisition Corp.   Financial   Shell Companies USA 328.16M -   10.22   0.20%   1200
52  53  ACB Aurora Cannabis Inc.    Healthcare  Drug Manufacturers - Specialty & Generic    Canada  616.72M -   1.33    1.53%   7895713
53  54  ACCD    Accolade, Inc.  Healthcare  Health Information Services USA 621.64M -   8.61    5.13%   363498
54  55  ACCO    ACCO Brands Corporation Industrials Business Equipment & Supplies   USA 517.53M 27.54   5.48    0.74%   466342
55  56  ACDC    ProFrac Holding Corp.   Energy  Oil & Gas Equipment & Services  USA 3.90B   61.26   24.81   -3.54%  329691
56  57  ACEL    Accel Entertainment, Inc.   Consumer Cyclical   Gambling    USA 757.39M 11.83   8.65    -1.37%  132148
57  58  ACER    Acer Therapeutics Inc.  Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 18.35M  -   1.17    3.54%   45443
58  59  ACES    ALPS Clean Energy ETF   Financial   Exchange Traded Fund    USA -   -   55.29   1.52%   14477
59  60  ACET    Adicet Bio, Inc.    Healthcare  Biotechnology   USA 713.11M -   17.20   -2.88%  441691
```

Relevant documentation for packages used:

- [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/)
- [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)
- [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)